# how to dynamically create new worksheets in excel using ssis

Tags: excel, ssis

I follow all the instructions on every website but always get an error with the excel destination saying "make sure the object exists... Please help me

thanks

Comment: can you specify more details... I am guessing you are using dynamic connection without set `delay validation` to `TRUE`

Comment: I am able to create new excel tabs with the appropriate names however the result set is going only into the first tab when it should be divided out by tab name which is equal to the variable that I set in the source of the data flow.